# Google API java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception

Tags: java, exception, google-maps

I am interested to create a pure Standalone Java application(no Applet,no JSP nothing) that has one **TEXTBOX** that takes an address and divides it in **City,State,Zip,Country** using **Google Api**. 
For that I created one  **net beans** project that is doing exactly the same but if I want to create like this :

```
GClientGeocoder gc=GClientGeocoder.create();
gc.getLocations(add,this);
```

it shows an **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError**

Now the class definition is like this :

```
public class GoogleApiView extends FrameView implements GGeocodeAdvancedResultListener{
    bla bla bla.................
}
```

If I comment the code of **GclientGeocoder** it doesn't gives an exception. 
Again the thing is that I want this code to work perfectly because its the only thing that gives me addresses in the form of **State,City,Zip,Country**.

What should I do to remove this exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mapitz.gwt.googleMaps.client.GClientGeocoderImpl.create()Lcom/mapitz/gwt/googleMaps/client/GClientGeocoder;
at com.mapitz.gwt.googleMaps.client.GClientGeocoderImpl.create(Native Method)
at com.mapitz.gwt.googleMaps.client.GClientGeocoder.create(GClientGeocoder.java:36)
at googleapi.GoogleApiView.btnOkActionPerformed(GoogleApiView.java:281)
at googleapi.GoogleApiView.access$800(GoogleApiView.java:34)
at googleapi.GoogleApiView$4.actionPerformed(GoogleApiView.java:164)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0):

What environment are you running this in?  Just doing the usual rounds around the web it looks like when the JVM attempts to run the create() method some OS specific (native to that environment) is being called and is subsequently dying

**UnsatifiedLinkError**

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

You may need to fully setup your environment or read the API specs and determine what native environments are supported.  You may simply be missing some files that need to be included as part of the build process.

The following link gives some more detail on the GClientGeocoder API http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GClientGeocoder and also recommends the HTTP Geocoder as an alternative.

Comment: I am using windows environment.

Comment: The documentation you linked is the documentation of Classes involved in JavaScript or may be we can say that, that they are going to be used with JavaScript, but I want something that can be integrated with standalone program in Java.

Comment: Which version of the library are you using?  Do you have an API key? http://geo-google.sourceforge.net/usage.html and http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html?  Sorry on the javascript version links, looks like per the google documentation they are migrating away from version 2 (java libraries) in favor of version 3 an api-key-less javascript version.